# show the message time in the inbox php

Tags: php, datetime

Hi i am doing internal mail service application ,

i have the field called datetime in my table,

i want to show the mail datetim in the inbox view somthing like gmail inbox,

i want to show if the mail came just 10 min aga means , i want to show 10min ago,

if mail came around 2 days back means i want to show the DATE-Time ,

**Thing keep in mind** i maintain the DATETIME datatyoe ,

Thanks
Bharanikumar

This is snippet i have...

> list($date, $time) = explode(' ', $session_time);
>
> list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);
>
> list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $time);
>
> $session_time = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
>
> $time_difference = time() - $session_time ;
>
> echo $seconds = $time_difference ;
>
> $minutes = round($time_difference / 60 );
>
> $hours = round($time_difference / 3600 );
>
> $days = round($time_difference / 86400 );
>
> $weeks = round($time_difference / 604800 );
>
> $months = round($time_difference / 2419200 );
>
> $years = round($time_difference / 29030400 );
>
> if($days>2){
>
> echo date("d-m-Y G:i",$session_time);
>
> }else
>
> // Seconds
>
> if($seconds <= 60)
>
> {
>
> echo "test$seconds seconds ago";
>
> }
>
> //Minutes
>
> else if($minutes <=60)
>
> {
>
> if($minutes==1)
>
> {
>
> echo "1 minute ago";
>
> }
>
> else
>
> {
>
> ```
> echo "$minutes minutes ago";
> ```
>
> }
>
> }
>
> //Hours
>
> else if($hours <=24)
>
> {
>
> if($hours==1)
>
> {
>
> echo "1 hour ago";
>
> }
>
> else
>
> {
>
> echo "$hours hours ago";
>
> }

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want it what people call Pretty Date. [Here is the basic algorithm JavaScript](http://ajaxian.com/archives/do-you-have-a-pretty-date). You should be able to easily port it to PHP.